# How to create the UI for different devices in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm working with an iOS application in which i uses the different controllers with 4 inch screen sizes.

I'm done with my application. Now it is the requirement that it also runs on the 3.5 inch screen like on iPhone 4S. I am using the auto layout. How can i do it?

This is my first application.So I have a little knowledge about UI.

My requirement is that when I run the same application on iPhone 4S with 3.5 inch screen size, it needs to be reset automatically with 3.5 inch.

Please help me out.

Comment: Are u using XIB or Storyboard? Please mention it...

Comment: @hirn  i am using xib

Answer (score -2):

Use the iOS Simulator, that will give you an idea of how the application will turn out (Whilst you're in in choose Hardware -> Device -> iPhone Retina (3.5 inch).

You can adjust elements in interface builder to scale to different elements on the screen under the view tab. Try using the view tab (looks like a ruler) and specify the origin and scaling there.